# Postman using Slack integration to notify for 3 failures and then first success

Tags: postman, monitoring, slack-api

**Question:** How can I set up Postman with Slack integrations to notify only for failures and then first success?

I had this configured in the past, but lost it recently when a collection was accidentally deleted.
Over 2019, I created monitors with Postman through the online dashboard with Slack integrations.
I believe during the setup there was an option under "Additional Preferences" to "Notify for 3 failures and then first success". 
[As of 2020, this option is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljQ1u.png).

Other seem to have used the same functionality ([Example 1](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4274), [Example 2](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5931)), but I cannot see evidence of it in the [official documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/monitors/setting-up-monitor/#creating-a-monitor-via-a-collection), and official posts refer to workarounds [like this](https://community.postman.com/t/notify-slack-when-test-failures-are-found/175).

Is it currently possible?

Comment: You're better off asking these types of questions in the Postman community site. https://community.postman.com

Comment: Thank you @DannyDainton, I have raised it there and will copy any resolution across here.